# Azure Authentication Id is not stable

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-authentication

I am using Azure mobile app services with Xamarin Forms.
In my app, I use web social media authentication (Facebook, Twitter, Google) configured in the azure portal.

I am taking the sid gotten from CurrentClient.Id to match it with users in my Easy Tables. However, for some users, after logging in with the same account and same provider, no match is found in my database because the sid is different! I am 100% sure that it is the same account used to login before, yet I get a different sid. How is that possible? Shouldn't it remain the same with every login or what's the whole point of it then?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you facing the same issue as discussed in this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489783/has-azure-user-ids-changed-their-format, if yes, could you please try the workaround mentioned in this URL and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @AjayKumar-MSFT, I am using node.js as my backend not C#. And I didn't find an equivalent of this in node.js. This problem affects my entire app and should never happen in the first place, and a workaround is not acceptable as a solution, I need a reliable solution that I can trust for my users.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Azure App Service Authentication for this.  There is a stable ID that is available within the JWT that you pass to the service.  You can easily get it from the /.auth/me endpoint (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#validate-tokens-from-providers )

When you GET /.auth/me with the X-ZUMO-AUTH header set to the authenticationToken returned from the login, the user.userId field will be populated with a stable ID.  So, the next question is "how do I add this / compare this within the Node.js backend?"  Fortunately, the [HOW-TO FAQ for Node.js](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps/howto/server/nodejs/#use-authentication-claims-with-your-tables) explicitly answers this.  Short version is, use `context.user.getIdentity()` (an async method) to get the identity, then do something with it:

```js
function queryContextFromUserId(context) {
  return context.user.getIdentity().then((data) => {
    context.query.where({ id: data.userId });
    return context.execute();
  });
}

function addUserIdToContext(context) {
  return context.user.getIdentity().then((data) => {
    context.itme.id = data.userId;
    return context.execute();
  });
}

table.read(queryContextFromUserId);
table.insert(addYserIdToContext);
table.update(queryContextFromUserId);
table.delete(queryContextFromUserId);
```

The real question here is "what is in the data block?"  It's an object that contains "whatever the /.auth/me endpoint with the X-ZUMO-AUTH header produces", and that is provider dependent.

The mechanism to figure this out.

1. Debug your client application - when the login completes, inspect the client object for the CurrentUser and get the current token
2. Use Fiddler, Insomnia, or Postman to GET .../.auth/me with an X-ZUMO-AUTH header set to the current token
3. Repeat for each auth method you have to ensure you have the formats of each one.

You can now use these in your backend.